# How to plot data from two columns of Excel Spreadhseet using madplotlib and numpy to make a line graph/plot

Tags: matplotlib

Link to the Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c2hItirdrnvz2emJ4peJHaWrQlzahoHeVqetgHHAXvI/edit?usp=sharing

I am new to Python and am very keen to learn this since I like statistics and computer programming. Any help would be appreciated!

I used matploylib and numpy, but don't know how to graph this spreadsheet as a line graph.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('name_of_csv.csv); df.plot()` should get you stared

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it!

Answer (score 5):

If the data are in a common csv (comma separable values) format, they can easily be read into python. (Here I downloaded the file from the link in the question via File/Download as/comma separated values.

#### Using pandas and matplotlib

You can then read in data in pandas using `pandas.read_csv()`. This creates a `DataFrame`. Usually pandas automatically understands that the first row is the column names. You can then access the columns from the Dataframe via their names.

Plotting can easily performed with the `DataFrame.plot(x,y)` method, where x and y can be simply the column names to plot.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# reading in the dataframe from the question text
df = pd.read_csv("data/1880-2016 Temperature Data Celc.csv")

# make Date a true Datetime
df["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year"], format="%Y")

# plot dataframe 
ax = df.plot("Year", "Temperature in C")

ax.figure.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

In case one wants a scatterplot, use

```
df.plot( x="Year", y="Temperature in C", marker="o", linestyle="")
```

#### Using numpy and matplotlib

The same can be done with numpy. Reading in the data works with `numpy.loadtxt` where one has to provide a little bit more information about the data. E.g. expluding the first row and using comma as separator. The unpacked columns can be plotted with pyplot `pyplot.plot(year, temp)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# reading in the data 
year, temp = np.loadtxt("data/1880-2016 Temperature Data Celc.csv", 
                        skiprows=1, unpack=True, delimiter=",")
#plotting with pyplot 
plt.plot(year, temp, label="Temperature in C")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Temperature in C")
plt.legend()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

The result looks roughly the same as in the pandas case (because pandas simply uses matplotlib internally).

[image]

In case one wants a scatterplot, there are two options:

```
plt.plot(year, temp, marker="o", ls="", label="Temperature in C")
```

or

```
plt.scatter(year, temp, label="Temperature in C")
```

Comment: The line that makes the date a true Datetime is not working for me

Comment: You can comment that line out,if you want. Though I don't know why it shouldn't work. What's the error? Mind the first sentence I added to the answer.

Comment: Thank You So Much! IT actually worked! Thank You!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: How can you do this data for scatter plots?